# User Ampscript to retrieve user information

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ampscript

I am a beginner in Marketing Cloud. I try to write a simple Ampscript with SOAP API on a landing page to show user information but InvokeRetrieve always returns nothing.

Here is my sample code.

```
  %%[
    SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
    SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "AccountUser")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","CustomerKey")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","Name")

    SET @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "Property", "CustomerID")
    SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp, "Value", "72146")
    SetObjectProperty(@rr, "Filter", @sfp)
    SET @tsd = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)

    SET @rowCount = Rowcount(@tsd)
  ]%%
  Rows:%%=v(@rowCount)=%%
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`CustomerID` property is not part of the [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm) Object so you can use other AccountUser object property to get the user Information.

I used my **UserID** (i.e UserName) to get my user information in below code.

```
%%[
    SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
    SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "AccountUser")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","CustomerKey")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","Name")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","ID")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","UserID")

    SET @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "Property", "UserID")
    SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp, "Value", "Palash_07")
    SetObjectProperty(@rr, "Filter", @sfp)
    SET @tsd = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)

     IF RowCount(@tsd) > 0 THEN
    SET @Name = FIELD(Row(@tsd,1), "Name")  
    EndIF
]%%

UserName: %%=v(@Name)=%% <br/>
```